# Add style if there are more than one image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a text editor for posts that creates `<p>` for each part of the content.

Sometimes the content contains 1 image or more and sometimes no images.

```css
.post{
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff
}

.post img + img{
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <p>First Post</p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div> <!-- .post -->
    
<div class="post">
    <p>Second Post</p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div> <!-- .post -->
```

So If there are two images, I want each one to take `50%` of the width.

I can set the width of the second image:

```
.posts img + img{
    width:50%
}
```

But how to select the first one?

Here is a live fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zjwhgq81/14/

I need a x-browser compatible solution that is supported in most of the browsers on different browsers.

Please don't suggest adding a class or an id to the `img`, As I mention I'm using a text editor.

Comment: I think you can use flexbox for that?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, I think this could be done, But I think flexbox is supported for modern browsers

Comment: But I don't mind checking it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Select post with one child

```
.post p img:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Select post with more child

```
/* Select the first of more */
.post p img:nth-child(1) {
    width:60%
}

/* Select others of more except the first */
.post p img:nth-child(n+2) {
    width: 10%;
}
```

```css
.post{
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  width:100%;
}

.post p img:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

.post p img:nth-child(1) {
    width:60%
 
}

.post p img:nth-child(n+2) {
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <p>First Post</p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div> <!-- .post -->
    
<div class="post">
    <p>Second Post</p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div> <!-- .post -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.post p img:first-child, .post p img:last-child {
  width:50%;
}
.post p img:last-child:first-child {
    width:100%
}
```

or

```
   .post p img {
      width:50%;
    }
    .post p img:last-child:first-child {
        width:100%
    }
```

when there is only one image the first and last is the same so you can set that to either 100% or anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYou can use Jquery to determinate the width of each img. For me, the easiest way to do it would be like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < $('.post p').length; i++) {
 let items = $($('.post p')[i]).children();
 items.css('width', (100 / items.length) + '%');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #111;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.post{
  background-color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.post img {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post">
    <h2>First Post</h2>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div>
    
<div class="post">
    <h2>Second Post</h2>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/200">
    </p>
</div>
```